# How do the io.Pipe Write() and Read() functions work?

Tags: go, pipe

By reading golang src [pipe.go](https://golang.org/src/io/pipe.go) to figure out how pipe works, I ran into these two write() & read() functions. What confuses me is that if reader calls read() func and hold l.lock and then waiting for data, how does writer call write() func and acquire l.lock to write data in?

```
func (p *pipe) write(b []byte) (n int, err error) {
    // pipe uses nil to mean not available
    if b == nil {
        b = zero[:]
    }

    // One writer at a time.
    p.wl.Lock()
    defer p.wl.Unlock()

    p.l.Lock()
    defer p.l.Unlock()
    if p.werr != nil {
        err = ErrClosedPipe
        return
    }
    p.data = b
    p.rwait.Signal()
    for {
        if p.data == nil {
            break
        }
        if p.rerr != nil {
            err = p.rerr
            break
        }
        if p.werr != nil {
            err = ErrClosedPipe
            break
        }
        p.wwait.Wait()
    }
    n = len(b) - len(p.data)
    p.data = nil // in case of rerr or werr
    return
}
```

and read:

```
func (p *pipe) read(b []byte) (n int, err error) {

    // One reader at a time.
    p.rl.Lock()
    defer p.rl.Unlock()

    p.l.Lock()
    defer p.l.Unlock()
    for {
        if p.rerr != nil {
            return 0, ErrClosedPipe
        }
        if p.data != nil {
            break
        }
        if p.werr != nil {
            return 0, p.werr
        }
        p.rwait.Wait()
    }
    n = copy(b, p.data)
    p.data = p.data[n:]
    if len(p.data) == 0 {
        p.data = nil
        p.wwait.Signal()
    }
    return
}
```

Comment: I don't know much about sync.Cond, but it is interesting that `p.rwait.L = &p.l` and `p.wwait.L = &p.l`. There's something up with the wait/signal pairs that I don't quite understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mutex `p.l` is used in the read and write [`sync.Cond`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Cond) conditions, which will lock and unlock it as necessary.

Calling `Wait` on the condition unlocks its lock, and waits for a corresponding `Signal` call. You can see that the pipe uses `p.wwait` and `p.rwait` to coordinate the readers and writers within the `Read` and `Write` methods.

Comment: Very good catch. I finally realized what sync.Cond is good for digging into this.

Comment: @captncraig: yeah, I feel a simplified version of this exact Pipe code would make a good Cond example for the sync package.

Comment: Thanks @JimB. I tried to tar & stream objects to AWS using io.pipe, and gets err data truncated. It works if output to local file using io.pipe. Not sure why since io.pipe write() func is blocked till data is consumed by reader which will not cause any data leak.